# How to implement interface for class which methods defined in a prototype?

Tags: typescript

I have common logic between classes and I don't want to use inheritance. So I added all common methods through prototype, but when I implement interfaces for classes I got an error.
Example:

```
// types.ts
export interface IPlayer {
    go(): void
}

// entities.ts
import { IPlayer } from './types'    

class Player implements IPlayer {}

Player.prototype.go = function() {}
```

> Class 'Player' incorrectly implements interface 'IPlayer'.
>     Property 'go' is missing in type 'Player' but required in type 'IPlayer'

But if I define interface with the same name in the 'entities.ts', the error will go away:

```
 // types.ts
export interface IPlayer {
    go(): void
}

// entities.ts
import { IPlayer } from './types'    

interface Player extends Iplayer{}

class Player implements IPlayer {}

Player.prototype.go = function() {}
```

I think I missing the point on how interfaces work. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: Why are you not defining the methods in the class, like `class Player implements IPlayer { go() {} }` ?

Comment: You are seeing interface-class merging. I would definitely implement like @jcalz suggests. But the option you discovered with interface-class merging is the way to go if you want to use prototype assignment instead. (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir it is a common method between several classes and I don't want to use inheritance, there some other common method and composition fits better in my case

Comment: @IvanSemochkin mixins perhaps ? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks maybe mixins is a way to go, I'll look at it